# How to do self-referential select on hierarchical data in DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datatable

I have a DataTable with, let's say, two columns: ReportId and ParentReportId. I want to select all of the reports whose Parent is NOT already listed in the DataTable. I want to do something like this (taking from SQL syntax), but I know this doesn't work:

```
DataRow[] foo = drParentRow = dt.Select("ParentReportId NOT IN(ReportId)");
```

How can I get these records from this dataset in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

```
var noParents = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["ReportParentID"] != DBNull.Value && 
                                      !dt.rows.Any(y => y["ReportID"] == x["ReportParentID"]);
```

Comment: dt.Rows doesn't have a .Where() method. I am using System.Data and System.Linq.

Comment: I updated the answer a few mins ago, you have to do dt.AsEnumerable().Where()

Comment: Just a note: I've always wondered why C# people are writing `AsEnumerable()` explicitely in their LINQ queries on DataTables, because i'm not forced to do so in VB. Now i know that this is one of the (few) VB.NET advantages(normally VB is more verbose):  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2008/05/14/how-linq-to-dataset-works-in-vb-jonathan-aneja.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to use some LINQ for this:

```
var reportIds = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<int>("ReportId"));

var foo = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
          let parentReportId = row.Field<int>("ParentReportId")
          where !reportIds.Contains(parentReportId)
          select row;
```